# Control line and paragraph spacing in RMarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

The title says it all, how do I control line and paragraph spacing in Rmarkdown?

Essentially I want to have different line spacing for different paragraphs - some single spaced and some double spaced (or preferably one-and-a-half spacing), but Rmarkdown doesn't seem to recognize `\singlespacing` `doublespacing` or `\onehalfspacing` that I find elsewhere for LaTeX documents.

For paragraph spacing, I'm able to use `\setlength{\parskip}{-1em}` to get no spacing between paragraphs, but this just seems wrong with `-1em`

Comment: Individually or for the whole document?

Comment: Could you please provide your YAML?

Comment: @bttomio - for individual paragraphs

Comment: @bttomio - the YAML is very bare bones - 

output: pdf_document